# The function d3ddev->Present() doesn't work when I copy the backbuffer to the screen

Tags: c++, direct3d

When I use `d3ddev->Present()` to copy the back buffer to the screen,  nothing happened (the return value is `D3D_OK`). When I create a window without titlebar such as `WS_POPUP`, it works. Is there someone who can tell me why? Thanks.
and sorry for poor English.

win10, Direct3D9

[window without titlebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUeVq.png)

[window with titlebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rLUw.png)
...

```
//Game update function

void Game_Run(HWND hwnd)
{
    //make sure the Direct3D device is valid
    if (!d3ddev) return;
    //start rendering
    if (SUCCEEDED(d3ddev->BeginScene())) {
        //fill the surface with random color
        int r = rand() % 255;
        int g = rand() % 255;
        int b = rand() % 255;
        d3ddev->ColorFill(surface, NULL, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(r, g, b));
        //copy the surface to the backbuffer
        RECT rect;
        rect.left = rand() % SCREENW / 2;
        rect.right = rect.left + rand() % SCREENW / 2;
        rect.top = rand() % SCREENH / 2;
        rect.bottom = rect.top + rand() % SCREENH / 2;
        d3ddev->StretchRect(surface, NULL, backbuffer, &rect, D3DTEXF_NONE);
        //stop rendering
        d3ddev->EndScene();
        //copy the back buffer to the screen
        d3ddev->Present(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    }
    //check for escape key
    if (KEY_DOWN(VK_ESCAPE))
        PostMessage(hwnd, WM_DESTROY, 0, 0);
}
...
//create a new window
HWND hwnd = CreateWindow(
    "MainWindowClass",
    APPTITLE.c_str(),
    WS_POPUP,                   //it works
    //WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,        it doesn't work
    CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
    SCREENW, SCREENH,
    NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
```

Comment: Not sure why you are using legacy Direct3D9 in the first place, but you can find some working 'basic render loops' for DirectX 11 [here](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll read some books about DirectX 11.@ChuckWalbourn